# cloning same record with some explicit values in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table with id,name,place,time,refer columns.
Now i need to clone the record with some condition for id column.
But time and refer columns should be inserted explicitly.
My query is

```
 INSERT INTO table_name(id,name,place,time,refer columns) select id,name,place from table_name where id='1')
```

Comment: Can you provide an example.

Comment: why don't you just clone it, then update it after?

Comment: Your query is wrong. it will throw an error. You have to provide all values with the cols you are using with table name

Comment: id,name,place values taking from select query and time and refer values to be defined explicitly.